# Why would a programmer want to separate each function to its own assembly or project?

Tags: class, function

I was just wondering why would a programmer want to have one class library or project per function? I have a client and want it to be in separate assembly for each function.

I am not sure of the purpose but can anybody tell me the advantage? purpose or benefit of it?

ex. `SearchPerson(){}` and `GetAllEmails(){}` are different function but why not just put it in the same solution just different class?

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of high modularity, is that (given the code is written for high reuseability) you could easily restructure the final build, patch a production envrionment, by only affecting a small part of the solution etc.

It is always a trade off. One large solution might be easier to manage in the development phase.